# VB.NET - Split array of objects into smaller arrays based on value

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, split

I have an array of type `Material` that I want to split into smaller groups. A `Material` is an object composed of a `Type`, `Description`, and `Value`. I want to display the materials' `Description` and `Value` grouped together by `Type` so that I can display them sort of like this:

```
For Each matTypeGroup As Material() In matTypeGroups
    DisplayTypeName(matTypeGroup(0).Type) 

    For Each mat As Material In matTypeGroup
        DisplayMaterialInfo(mat.Description, mat.Value) 
    Next
Next
```

The final output would look something like this:

```
- Type1
    Description1: Value1
    Description2: Value2
    Description3: Value3
- Type2
    Description4: Value4
- Type3
    Description5: Value5
    Description6: Value6
```

**How do I split the `Material` array into an array of `Material` arrays grouped by `Type`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim matTypeGroups = materials.GroupBy(Function(m) m.Type)
```

You just need to edit your code to work with IGrouping instead of arrays. I assumed the Type is a string here.

```
For Each matTypeGroup As IGrouping(Of String, Material) In matTypeGroups
    DisplayTypeName(matTypeGroup.Key) 

    For Each mat As Material In matTypeGroup
        DisplayMaterialInfo(mat.Description, mat.Value) 
    Next
Next
```

Comment: That was going to be my answer as well. While this answer won't return an Array it will group it the way you want. If you need to know how to use it  look up IGrouping on the MSDN.

Comment: Couldn't you call .ToList() and still work with it like an array - using items in the List by index.

Comment: You could but in this case working with the IGrouping directly works just as well.